# How Do I Get Top 3 values to go in ascending rather than descending order in R/ dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working in dplyr, and reshape:

The Df I have has a list of 45 cities with about 10 columns of data for each city. I want the three smallest values for each city/row.

I am able to get them through this:

```
new_df <- melt(Df) ## giving me the long form of the data
newer_df2$value2 <- new_df$value * -1
top3 <- newer_df %>% group_by(City) %>% arrange(value2) %>% top_n(3)
```

Giving me for example:

```
City    Value
City 1  -1000
City 1   -999
City 1   -998
city 2   -500
city 2   -499
city 2   -498`
```

etc...

So while this is technically the answer, it would be much easier to have it in the reverse order, as below, so I can export it as a csv without needing to format it in excel.

```
City    Value
City 1   -998
City 1   -999
City 1   -1000
city 2   -498
city 2   -499
city 2   -500`
```

** When i don't multiply by -1, it gives me the three highest values, but in the correct order

Comment: Starting in dplyr 0.5, you can select the bottom `n` values using negative values in `top_n`.  To get the lowest 3 values of `value` you could use `top_n(-3, value)`.

Comment: You haven't taken a glance at the doc for `arrange`. The first line says `"Use desc to sort a variable in descending order."`

Comment: When multiplying by negative one for sorting you don't have to store the result in a new variable. `arrange(-value)` will work just as well as `arrange(desc(value))`. The `desc()` approach is more flexible because it will work for non-numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may want to use `arrange` *after* `top_n`. For example:

```
new_df %>% top_n(-3, value) %>% arrange(desc(value))
```

Comment: The -3, gets rid of all the observations.